# For-each not iterating properly

Tags: java, foreach

I got this for-each loop that isn't iterating correctly my ArrayList of object 'CharacterMove'. I know it's not empty since i tried printing size() right before it iterates

Here's the for-each i have

```
for (CharacterMove move : charinfo.getMoves()) {
```

The ArrayList

```
private List<CharacterMove> moveset = new ArrayList<>();
```

Anyone?

Edit:
Here's the full method

```
public static void writeDataFromChara(CharacterInfo charinfo, String fileTarget, boolean popupFail) {
    try {
        File file = new File(fileTarget);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(file);

        ps.print("<INFO>");
        ps.println();

        System.out.println("Size: " + charinfo.getMoves().size());

        //Write the information
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : charinfo.tree.getAllDatas().entrySet()) {
            ps.print(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
            ps.println();
        }

        //Write the moves, frames and hitboxes
        for (CharacterMove move : charinfo.getMoves()) {
            System.out.println("Z"); //Never called just like everything else
            ps.print(move.name + ":");
            ps.println();
            for (Pair<CharacterMoveFrame,Integer> frame : move.frames) {
                ps.print("frame:"); //Indicate that this is part of a new frame
                for (Entry<String, Collider> collider : frame.left.hitboxes.entrySet()) {
                    ps.print(collider.getValue().x + ",");
                    ps.println();
                    ps.print(collider.getValue().y + ",");
                    ps.println();
                    ps.print(collider.getValue().w + ",");
                    ps.println();
                    ps.print(collider.getValue().h);
                    ps.println();
                }
            }
        }
        ps.close();
    } catch (IOException e0) {
        if (popupFail) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JPanel(), "An error happened while writing the data", "Error", 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say it's not iterating "properly": You mean that whatever is inside the loop is never happening?

Comment: And what does `moveset` have to do with the `for` loop you're showing? Perhaps you could show a complete example of what you're doing (perhaps a simplified version that reproduces the problem) rather than just those two lines?

Comment: Post more of the loop code - especially the `for` line (exactly, so copy-paste it) and if it's not too much code, the whole loop

Comment: Yeah, whatever is inside of my loop is never called.

Comment: Alright after further investigation, it seems that the foreach did work but it was the first loop that was bugging.

Comment: Wanna close this question then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this line;

```
   System.out.println("Size: " + charinfo.getMoves().size());
```

If the size is '0', your first for-each loop doesn't work.